# Obtain values from a slack webhook and add to a text file. Is this possible?

Tags: webhooks, slack, endpoint, payload

I have currently setup a webhook with a repository platform called cloudsmith.io. The webhook is currently working perfectly. But I want to know if it is possible to add these slack messages to a text file so I can create some form of change log. Is this possible?

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad so I will just comment. No, you can not obtain values from a Slack webhook. But you can obtain messages from a Slack channel and store them in a text file to create a log. The easiest is to call [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) and then filter and store what you need.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I agree my question is very broad, but appreciate the help! I will start looking down this route now, many thanks!